# I'm a total noob and need to know if Ubuntu will work properly in my laptop

Tags: 12.04, laptop, samsung

So, as the title says: I'm not very tech savvy, but I tried Ubuntu and loved it!

The thing is: I don't know if my laptop can handle Ubuntu or if I need to do something special to make it work properly (like drivers or some other add-on).

Samsung 300e4a, currently running WIN 7.

500 GB Hard Drive, 8GB RAM, Intel(R) HD Graphics, Realtek High Definition Audio

Comment: You should always check if the OS you are curious about has a "hardware compatibility" list, or a 'certification' site...
http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/models/

Comment: And, if you find any answers below are more helpful than the stock answer, please post that here.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Universal USB Installer for Windows](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/), and once installed, launch it. Choose the Ubuntu distribution you like, and have the app download it for you onto a USB flash drive. Then, reboot your PC, and choose to boot from the flashdrive. That will start the version of Linux you chose as a LiveUSB, which will be able to use data files (music, video, text, graphics) on your hard drive. When you know which version you like the best, then you can install it from the LiveUSB; if you chose to, you can resize the Windows partition, leaving Windows intact, and install Ubuntu alongside Windows.

There are [many versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions#Official_distributions) so I suggest you try several, and choose the version you like. There are differences in both the [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) as well as the apps and utilities they use; suggest you pick the desktop you like ([Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/) vs [Classic GNOME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME) vs [KDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE) vs [Xfce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce) vs [LXDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXDE)) and if there's a different app you find in one distro which you want in another (e.g., a different [file manager](http://www.tuxarena.com/2011/06/20-file-managers-for-ubuntu/)), you can install it later.  I prefer Xubuntu 13.10 right now on my [Lenovo T500](http://www.notebookreview.com/notebookreview/lenovo-t500-thinkpad-review/) but your mileage will vary.

Just like you can have both Windows 7 as well as Ubuntu on your machine, you can also add multiple versions of Linux, and choose what you want to run at boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try the "Try ubuntu" options from a installation CD/USB. If everything works, it can work.

[Grab the version you want here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Burn it to a CD or make a bootable USB. When booting your computer, interrupt your BIOS and find the option to select a bootable device. Select the USB or CD and you should be able to reach the "Try Ubuntu" option.

Comment: I already booted from a USB drive and found no apparent problems, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing any vital info... Thanks a lot!